# How to define a dynamic block for advanced_filter

Tags: terraform, azure-eventgrid, azure-rm

I want to define multiple filters for azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription module

i tried by creating a dynamic block like below :

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "subscription" {
  name                 = var.subscription_data["name"]
  scope                = var.subscription_data["scope"]
  expiration_time_utc  = var.subscription_data["expiration_time_utc"]
  included_event_types = var.included_event_types
  dynamic "advanced_filter" {
    for_each = var.advanced_filter
    content {
      dynamic "bool_equals" {
        for_each = try(var.advanced_filter.value.bool_equals, {})
        content {
          key   = "test"
          value = true
          # values = try(bool_equals.value.value_list, null)
        }
      }
    }
  }

variable "advanced_filter" {
  type = map(any)
  description = "Advanced filter maps"
}
```

Terraform Doc : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/eventgrid_event_subscription
But getting some error like this:

```
Error: Missing required argument

  on ../main.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "subscription":
   1: resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "subscription" {

"advanced_filter.0.number_not_in": one of
`advanced_filter.0.bool_equals,advanced_filter.0.is_not_null,advanced_filter.0.is_null_or_undefined,advanced_filter.0.number_greater_than,advanced_filter.0.number_greater_than_or_equals,advanced_filter.0.number_in,advanced_filter.0.number_in_range,advanced_filter.0.number_less_than,advanced_filter.0.number_less_than_or_equals,advanced_filter.0.number_not_in,advanced_filter.0.number_not_in_range,advanced_filter.0.string_begins_with,advanced_filter.0.string_contains,advanced_filter.0.string_ends_with,advanced_filter.0.string_in,advanced_filter.0.string_not_begins_with,advanced_filter.0.string_not_contains,advanced_filter.0.string_not_ends_with,advanced_filter.0.string_not_in`
must be specified


Error: Missing required argument

  on ../main.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "subscription":
   1: resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "subscription" {

"advanced_filter.0.string_in": one of
`advanced_filter.0.bool_equals,advanced_filter.0.is_not_null,advanced_filter.0.is_null_or_undefined,advanced_filter.0.number_greater_than,advanced_filter.0.number_greater_than_or_equals,advanced_filter.0.number_in,advanced_filter.0.number_in_range,advanced_filter.0.number_less_than,advanced_filter.0.number_less_than_or_equals,advanced_filter.0.number_not_in,advanced_filter.0.number_not_in_range,advanced_filter.0.string_begins_with,advanced_filter.0.string_contains,advanced_filter.0.string_ends_with,advanced_filter.0.string_in,advanced_filter.0.string_not_begins_with,advanced_filter.0.string_not_contains,advanced_filter.0.string_not_ends_with,advanced_filter.0.string_not_in`
must be specified
```

Comment: What exactly is `var.advanced_filter`?

Comment: @Marcin 'var.advanced_filter' is the variable I defined. I've added that into the code.

Comment: I mean what is the actual value that you use of that variable.

Comment: That error is because at least one filter block needs to be declared in the resource. You need to ensure that at least one of those blocks exists, since currently your conditional ternary is resolving to iterating on an empty map. This would result in no filter blocks. You can add more dynamic blocks and ensure at least one produces content.

Comment: @Marcin This is the value i provided in terratest for that :  advanced_filter = {
    "bool_equals" = {
      key   = "test"
      value = true
    }

Comment: @MattSchuchard as per the above comment the value i am passing is confirmed that bool_equals as an argument to that variable.

Comment: Your structure should then be closer to `advanced_filter = { "bool_equals" =  true }`.

Answer (score 0):

I Put multiple dynamic blocks 1 for advanced_filter and another for each filters and it got worked

```
    resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "subscription" {
      name                 = var.subscription_data["name"]
      scope                = var.subscription_data["scope"]
      expiration_time_utc  = var.subscription_data["expiration_time_utc"]
      included_event_types = var.included_event_types
    
      dynamic "advanced_filter" {
        for_each = length(try(var.advanced_filter[0], [])) != 0 ? [var.advanced_filter] : []
        content {
          dynamic "bool_equals" {
            for_each = [for filter in advanced_filter.value : [filter.bool_equals] if try(filter.bool_equals, null) != null]
            content {
              key   = bool_equals.value[0].key
              value = bool_equals.value[0].value
            }
          }
    
          dynamic "number_greater_than" {
            for_each = [for filter in advanced_filter.value : [filter.number_greater_than] if try(filter.number_greater_than, null) != null]
            content {
              key   = number_greater_than.value[0].key
              value = number_greater_than.value[0].value
            }
          }
    
          dynamic "number_greater_than_or_equals" {
            for_each = [for filter in advanced_filter.value : [filter.number_greater_than_or_equals] if try(filter.number_greater_than_or_equals, null) != null]
            content {
              key   = number_greater_than_or_equals.value[0].key
              value = number_greater_than_or_equals.value[0].value
            }
          }
}
    variable "advanced_filter" {
      description = "Advanced filter maps"
      type        = any
      default     = []
    }
```

The terratest value should be like this:

```
advanced_filter = [
     {
       bool_equals = {
         key   = "test"
         value = true
      }
      },
    {
      number_not_in = {
        key    = "data.counter"
        values = [41, 0]
    } }
  ]
```